# Getting an error "Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'."

Tags: jsf, ejb-3.0, netbeans-7

So I connected to "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 " through Netbeans and then loaded all my entities.I followed the "https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html#createDB" tutorial to create some basic JSF's. It is working fine for all entities.But one of my entity name is "User" so when I try "Show all User Items" it gives me this error.

"Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'."

I tried to google this error and read in one of the posts that since "User" is a keywork I need to escape the name in the jpa.entities and make it @Table("\"User\"").I tired this also and it did not work.

I am new to using JSF's and working with netbeans and databases.Could you let me know what is causing this issue.Thanks.

Comment: Also to add when I use escape characters like mentioned above it throws an error saying "Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name"

Answer (score 2):

User is reserved word of SQLServer database, so you can't name your table with it. As group or role...
You could try use "Users" that will work fine!